# Function output type, specialised output or void?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been creating methods for a program of mine and I am now refactoring some code and I find I am changing all methods I initially made from:

```
public static string updateTextBox(string textbox){.... return "";}
```

to

```
public static void updateTextBox(TextBox textbox){...textbox.Text = "";}
```

I am doing this as with there are several advantages:
1.) first method I can only return a string and I found that sometimes I need to add more outputs(e.g change colour of the Foreground if an IF statement fails),  with the second method I just add a second parameter.

```
public static void updateTextbox(TextBox textbox1, TextBox textbox 2){...}
```

2.) I can exit code easily with second method

```
 return;
```

with first method the only thing I found was, which can cause errors

```
return null;
```

3.) It looks a lot cleaner when calling these methods

```
 textbox.Text = MethodClass.updateTextbox(TextBox textbox)


 MethodClass.updateTextbox(TextBox textbox)
```

I am a noob with programming still, is there something wrong with refactoring my methods to void types?

Comment: You can use extension methods

Comment: Is your method actually performing some computation? Would it *only* ever be used for TextBoxes? If the bulk of the code is working something out, I'd stick to the first version, personally, to separate the concerns of "computing a value" and "updating the UI".

Comment: @Jon Skeet, that's great, so if I'm mainly updating the UI (like if a value goes below a set limit, it changes foreground colour), ill stick to the first method, If I'm doing some calculations and want to output just a value, I'll use the first type

Comment: Well, I'd personally still try to isolate the UI-specific code from the *logical* code. You might want to look into the MVVM pattern...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Ok I will, thanks for the input

Comment: Note that you should name the methods appropriately. If the primary purpose of `updateTextBox` is to calculate a value, then it shouldn't be named `updateTextBox`, but rather something like `getCalculatedValue`. And If you decide that `updateTextBox` **should** update the textbox, then I would not have it return a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your requirement, whether you want to return a value form method or not. so if you want to update a class member then it's not necessary to return a value from the method which you want to set in your textbox. and it's not necessary to pass class members in your method, these are already accessible in the method.

If it's a reference type variable instead of a class member, you can pass it as a parameter and modify it inside the method itself. and if you have a value type then you can pass it as `ref` or `out` parameter.

So I would again say, it all depends on your requirement.

you can use your return value in the method for your logic purpose.  like if you have a method to check whether a number is a palindrome, so you will just return true or false, so in this case, the return type is useful. you could have plenty of scenarios where you want to return and where you don't want return value from a method.

If you have a method like `DoSomething`, It is just a simple method(like `int num = 1*2;`)and you don't care about its return value then you can use void type.